# In react how to check each element of array and print only some of them

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and have a project to do. I can iterate all array print all of them. How ever i just want to check my array and show only if it has specific info in it.This is my main iterating code.

```
      state = {
        top: [card1],
        bottom: [card2],
        rear: [card3],
        bottom2: [card4],
        bottom3: [card5],
        mycards: [card7,card8],
        myinfo: ["asd","card8"],
        transition: {
          item: null,
          startTop: 20,
          startAnim: true,
        }
      }

              <div ref={(node) => { this.mycardinfo = node; }}>
              {myinfo.map((item) => {
                const startTop = transition.item === item ? transition.startTop : 0;
                const animClass = transition.startAnim ? 'item-force-move' : '';
                const style = {
                  transform: `translateY(${startTop}px)`,
                }
                return (
                  <div 
                    className={`item item-mycard ${animClass}`}
                    onClick={(evt) => this.delete(item, evt)}
                    style={style}
                  >
                                {item}

                  </div>
```

I want to display only my "card8" element. However as it goes over all array it show both "asd" and "card8".

Comment: You can filter the array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just apply a filter to retrieve the item:

```
myinfo.filter(item=> item === "card8")[0]
```

Depending on whether you will have multiple "asd" items, you may want to remove the indexing. Filter will return a list of all items which match the conditional test, in this case `item==="asd"`

Comment: It is working also with myinfo.filter(item=> item != "asd")[0]

Comment: This will fail if filter returns an empty array.

Comment: True, however the concept of using a filter is still valid. As I said you may have multiple matching elements, so this is just representing the case posted.

Comment: But is it possible to get i-th element like if i want only use item[0] ?

Comment: Yes, in the filter function, the second, optional parameter is the index. So you could simply do the following: `myinfo.filter((item,idx) => (item==="card8" && idx===0))`

Comment: But it doesnt make sense to filter if you know the index. Simply access the array with that index directly.. `myinfo[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day sir =)

Answer (score 0):

Just use an *if statement* and return null if you don't want to map it:

```
if (item === "YOUR_CARD"){
  return <div>{item}</div>;
}else{
  return null;
}
```

Edit: As others have pointed out, you can also filter the array first and then map it:

```
myinfo.filter(item => item === "YOUR_CARD")
```

If you only want one card, use array.find and you'll get a single item back:

```
myinfo.find(item => item === "YOUR_CARD")
```

Comment: But is it possible to get i-th element like if i want only use item[0] ?